# Does Lothíriel effect resolves before Escort from Edoras forced effect?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

Lothíriel allows the player to put in play an ally during the questing phase, after she commits to the quest. That ally is then sent back to the player's hand at the end of the quest phase :

> **Response:** After Lothíriel commits to a quest, choose an ally in your hand. If that ally shares a Trait with her, put that ally into play exhausted and committed to the quest. At the end of the phase, if that ally is still in play, shuffle it into your deck.

A possible ally to use this effect on is "Escort from Edoras", whose forced effect discards him when the quest is resolved :

> **Forced:** After resolving a quest to which Escort from Edoras was committed, discard Escort from Edoras from play.

My question is can Lothíriel effect happen before Escord from Edoras forced effect?